# Convergence of a monotone sequence of bounded self-adjoint operators on a Hilbert space

Tags: operator-theory, self-adjoint-operators

Let $H$ be a complex Hilbert space and $(T_n)$ a monotonically nondecreasing sequence of bounded self-adjoint operators on $H$. It is well known that if there exists a bounded self-adjoint operator $K$ on $H$ such that every $T_i$ commutes with every $T_j$ and with $K$, then there exists a bounded self-adjoint operator $T$ such that $(T_n)$ strongly convergent to $T$ and $T\leq K$ (meaning $K-T$ is a positive operator).

My question is if there is an example of such a sequence of bounded self-adjoint operators (i.e. satisfying the stated conditions) but $(T_n)$ is not norm convergent to $T$? I tried google for it but it does not seem to turn anything up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works even without the commutativity assumptions. In any case, here is the canonical example.

Fix an increasing sequence of subspaces $H_n$ with $\bigcup_nH_n$ dense in $H$. Let $T_n$ be the orthogonal projection onto $H_n$. Then $\{T_n\}$ is increasing, it converges strongly to $I$, but $\|I-T_n\|=1$ for all $n$.